# javascript - can't compare var of type int in conditional statements

Tags: javascript, compare, conditional-statements

I declare global var in script sitting in the head:

```
var numMonsters;
```

then i have somebody setup div with form that call js function also located in the head and there i assigning this var:

```
 numMonsters = parseInt(document.getElementById("monsters").value , 10);
```

this is an element of that setup div.

later i replace divs with the display property : none/block

the new div contain my js game, there i want to use the value of that global var, but it won't stand even the simple conditional statement,
the chrome debugger shows the correct value, and it seems to be defined but it's realy not:

```
board = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    board[i] = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        board[i][j] = new Array();

        if ((i == 0) && (j == 0) && (numMonsters > 0)) {
            board[i][j][1] = true;
            board[i][j][2] = "red";
        }
        else if ((i == 9) && (j == 0) && (numMonsters > 1)) {
            board[i][j][1] = true;
            board[i][j][2] = "blue";
        }
        else if ((i == 9) && (j == 9) && (numMonsters > 2)) {
            board[i][j][1] = true;
            board[i][j][2] = "yellow";
        }
        else {
            board[i][j][1] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

this var gets one of the {0,1,2,3} values
if i considering only the i, j coordinates and then placing true it's doing the work
so it's the numMonsters that wo'nt function, and as i mentioned the chrome debugger shows good value for it.  it's droving me crazy, what am i doing wrong?! i also doing the same approach with other vars and they seems to work fine. thanks

Comment: What does the rest of your `if` statement look like? Add a radix to `parseInt` as well.

Answer (score 2):

That is working just fine.  It is likely something else in your code causing a problem.  Can you post some of the surrounding code?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gUKu/)

**HTML**

```
Monsters: <input id="monsters" type="text" value="10"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
var numMonsters = parseInt(document.getElementById("monsters").value, 10);

if (numMonsters > 0) {
    alert("Monsters win! Variable is a " + typeof numMonsters);
} else {
    alert("Fail.");
}
```

**EDIT:** Your code does not work because the "monsters" element does not exist in the DOM at the point you are trying to reference it.

Comment: but the debugger shows the right value. what do you mean, i'm new to javascript, do you mean it's checks the whole assignment while using the var? not only the value when it was assigned?

Comment: i also used other vars in the same methode and it's ok, i have a setup form in a div, and after validating it and assigning the values i'm going to use, i diplay the div that contain this game and using them, it's bad logic? how to pass values to such div with the javascript game..?

Comment: @k-man If you are doing variable assignment in the `<head>` tag based on elements in the DOM before the DOM is ready, the variables will evaluate to undefined.  You can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to execute a function after DOM is ready.